# add +1 class to owl-item in owl carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, owl-carousel

I'm trying to add a different class for each slide of my owl-carousel.

Example:

slide 1 will have for class

```
owl-item one
```

Slide 2 will have

```
owl-item two
```

etc

It needs to eb done via javascript / jquery as it for dynamic purpose.

Any help will be super !

Thank you !

Comment: What is the structure of your owl carousel, can you post the html code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you have class `owl-item` for your carousel slide items.

```
var classNum = ["one", "two", "three", "four", ...]
```

and use:

```
$.each($('.owl-item'), function(i, item) {
    $(item).addClass(classNum[i]);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

After owl has initialized, loop through owl items and add each of em a class.

```
$.each($('.owl-item'), function(i, item) {
    $(item).addClass('num-' + i);
    console.log(item);
});
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/cr29y1tc/25/